# Visual Studio 2022 no muestra el contenido de las variables

Tags: configuración, visual-studio-2022

Buen dia amigos

De un dia a otro me di cuenta que Visual Studio CE 2022 no me muestra el contenido de las variables al sobreponer el cursor.

Realmente no se que hice, no se si por error deshabilite esa opcion o se deshabilito.

A alguno de ustedes le pasó esto?, Saben como resolver el problema?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Revisa que en las opciones de ejecución no tengas puesto **release**, lo que deberías poner es **debug**, esto se configura justo al lado del botón donde ejecutas tu proyecto.

Comment: Olvide indicar que si tengo el modo debug, pero aun asi no muestra el contenido de las variables

Comment: Si tengo habilitado el modo debug, gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Que versión especifica estas usando?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64 bits) - Current Versión 17.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo hay que deshabilitar esta opcion, reiniciar el entorno y listo.

[image: Menu Herramientas/Opciones/Entorno/General]

Answer (score 1):

yo tengo ese mismo problema, pude solucionarlo temporalmente borrando la carpeta oculta .vs del proyecto, pero de rato vuelve a pasar, yo pienso que es problema de la versión de 17.8 y la 17.8.3 porque antes de esas no me pasaba

Comment: al parecer si es problema de esas versiones, según esto solo ocurre cuando esta conectado a un monitor extra, anexo la fuente: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-Release-178-Hovering/10518414?pageSize=15&sort=active&topics=vsts